# Effective action for chiral - anti-chiral interaction in 4d Chern-Simons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, effective-field-theory, chern-simons-theory, integrable-systems

So the question I have is regarding the derivation of eqn (2.9) of 'Gauge theory and Integrability III' by Costello and Yamazaki - https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.02289.

Beginning with 4d Chern-Simons, we have the following action

$$S_{4dCS}[A] =\int_{\Sigma \times C} \omega \wedge \text{CS}(A)  \; .$$

Where here $\Sigma$ is a 2 (real) dimensional worldsheet, $C$ is a riemann surface and $\omega$ is in general a meromorphic one form on $C$. For our purposes we will consider the simple case where $\omega = dz$ and $C=\mathbb{CP}^{1}$. Now we will want to insert order defects in this theory so consider adding of a single chiral defect with current $J$ and a single anti-chiral defect with current $\bar{J}$. These two currents couple to the partial gauge connection $A$ with an action of the form
$${S}_{4d-2d}= \int_{\Sigma \times \mathbb{CP}^{1}} dz\; \wedge \text{CS}(A) \; + \; \int _{\Sigma \times \lbrace {z}_{0} \rbrace} J_{w}{A}_{\bar{w}} \; + \; \int _{\Sigma \times \lbrace {z}_{1} \rbrace} \bar{J}_{\bar{w}}{A}_{{w}} \; .  $$
Where we have adopted complex coordinates $w, \, \bar{w}$ on our worldsheet $\Sigma$. Now here is the issue I have; when we integrate out the the gauge field $A$ from our action, we obtain the following 2d effective action,
$$ {S}^{\text{eff}}_{2d} = \int_{\Sigma} {r}_{ab}(z_{0}-{z}_{1}) {J}^{a} \bar{J}^{b} $$
My issue is the following, how do we derive this? Using the path integral approach to this question we have for wilson loop -esque observables

$$\langle \mathcal{O} \rangle = \frac{\int \mathcal{D}A \; \mathcal{D}J \;\mathcal{D}\bar{J} \; \mathcal{O} \text{ exp}(i{S}_{4d-2d}) }{\int \mathcal{D}A \; \mathcal{D}J \;\mathcal{D}\bar{J} \; \text{ exp}(i{S}_{4d-2d})} $$
I have seen from courses in QFT that usually one would perform this integral by putting the action in a quadratic form and then using a genralised Gaussian integral, this seems to be a difficult task here. Can anyone explain exactly/give any pointers to how one should proceed to explicitly integrate $A$ out explicitly from this formula and derive the 2d action? Is there a slick choice of gauge I can pick that'd allow me to see more clearly compute the functional integral over $A$?

Many thanks for your time.